# Sidekiq workers slower than Resque

Tags: ruby, heroku, amazon-ec2, resque, sidekiq

I am trying out sidekiq alongside my resque system in production.  Now I know this isn't quite an apples-to-oranges comparison but my resque jobs running on a heroku worker take around 4s to complete.  I am running only 50 threads on an amazon large instance with sidekiq and the same jobs take on average around 18s.  The jobs are very heavy on use of third-party apis so I am assuming my bottleneck is just my network connection but I just wanted to see if anyone has suggestions as to how I can better configure sidekiq.

Comment: if it takes 18s but you're doing 50 at a time that's still much faster throughput than a single heroku worker taking 4s per job

Comment: what version of ruby you use?

Answer (score 0):

Sidekiq workers will work parallel only if you will use jruby or rubinius, becouse ruby mri have global interpreter lock

Sidekiq workers will work faster only if you use jruby or rubinious with thread safe libriaries, that not block resoures that they use. So main reason of using sidekiq instead of resque is memory saving